# Factorising data from GoogleSheet and transforming it to Numeric in Multiple columns

Tags: r

First of all, I am a newbie learning R.

I have several GoogleSheet inputs (not many so I do that 1 by 1), but I am working with just one for now.
I need to go through several columns with the same factors and from string data, make numeric values based on factor levels, which is common in some cases to several columns but usually different. I select my columns based on the order (5 to 14).
Take into account that later I will need to merge all of my Google Sheets.

Tried this:

```
df<- read_sheet(URL)
colnames(df) <- c(col1, col2,col3.., col38)

#Make all strings as factor.
df[sapply(df, is.character)] <- lapply(df[sapply(df, is.character)], 
                                       as.factor)
for(i in 5:14) {       # for-loop over columns
  order <- c("Sí, me limita mucho" ,"Sí, me limita un poco" ,"No, no me limita nada")    
  df[ , i] <- factor(df[,i],levels = order)                                    
  df[,i]<-as.numeric(df[,i])                                                   
  }
```

If I call the column name, one by one, it works perfectly.

MANY THANKS!

```
order <- c("Sí, me limita mucho" ,"Sí, me limita un poco" ,"No, no me limita nada")
df$var1 <- factor(df$var1,levels = order)     
df$var1<-as.numeric(df$var1)
```

Comment: So is your problem solved ? If so, reply with an answer in the _Your Answer_ box and accept the answer. Or simply delete your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.